# Class hierarchy to have JTextField input initiate method calls

Tags: java, swing

My group and I are having some issues with a project topic we chose. In editing our program, I made a bit of a mess and we aren't sure how classes should communicate with one another exactly in terms of best practice or seeing the output we want.

Our issue at the moment is trying to have input from a JTextField (either n,w,s,e for directions) then act as a parameter to the keyPressed method (which takes a string), to then call the appropriate move method (taking int values for the row and column of our array/maze) and move the character square in our maze. We'd like the input from direction (JTextField object in the TextPanel class) act as a parameter to both the keyPressed method where it will take the string of n, w, s, e; and then ideally

We initially started by having all our logic without a GUI in one class, which would allow us to traverse the maze, so the issue is our GUI knowledge and how to properly increment our programming to test along the way.

Realize this is a fairly vague question, but looking for any insight on how to better organize this program to have the JTextField input invoke the other two methods.

Sample code:

```
package Project;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

//Creates a Maze Driver object, which adds a Dungeon and TextPanel 

public class MazeDriver 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    MazeDriver mazeDriver = new MazeDriver();   
 }

public MazeDriver(){  
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Maze Game");
    frame.add(new Dungeon());
    frame.setSize(180, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    TextPanel panel = new TextPanel();
    panel.setBackground (Color.white);
    panel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (800, 400));    

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();              
 }               
}

package Project;

//Creates the maze to be traversed 

public class Maze {
    private int[][] grid; 

    public Maze()
    {
        grid = new int[][]  { {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                              {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                              {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0, 1, 2} };
    }

    public int[][] getGrid(){
        return grid;
    } 
}

package Project;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Dungeon extends JPanel
{
    private Image grass, wall, boss;
    private Maze m;
    private Player p;

    public Dungeon()
    {
        m = new Maze();
        p = new Player();

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("grass.png");
        grass = img.getImage();

        img = new ImageIcon("wall.png");
        wall = img.getImage();

        img = new ImageIcon("boss.png");
        boss = img.getImage();

    }



    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        //for the dimensions of the maze array

        for(int x = 0; x < m.getGrid().length; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < m.getGrid()[x].length ;y++)
            {

               //if 2 meaning the boss square; 1 meaning a wall, 
                //0 meaning grass/maze path - draw the appropriate tile

               if(m.getGrid()[y][x] == 2) 
                   g.drawImage(boss, x*32, y*32, null);
               if(m.getGrid()[y][x] == 1)
                   g.drawImage(wall, x*32, y*32, null);
               if(m.getGrid()[y][x] == 0)
                   g.drawImage(grass, x*32, y*32, null);
            }
            g.drawImage(p.getPlayer(), p.getTileX()*32, p.getTileY()*32, null);
        }
    }

//public class Movement //implements ActionListener 
//{

        public int moveNorth(int row, int column){

        //if not falling off maze upwards

        if (row > 0)

          //if tile above is not a wall (1 value in array)  
        { if(m.getGrid()[row-1][column] != 1)
          {
            p.move(0, -1); 
          } else
            {
                System.out.println("You've hit a wall."); 
            }
        } else
          {
            System.out.println("You've hit a wall.");
          }
        return row;
        }

        //if not falling off maze downwards
        public int moveSouth(int row, int column){
            if (row < m.getGrid().length-1)
                //if tile below is not a wall (1 value in array)  
            { if(m.getGrid()[row+1][column] != 1)
              {
                p.move(0, 1);
              } else
                {
                    System.out.println("You've hit a wall.");
                }
            } else
              {
                System.out.println("You've hit a wall.");
              }
            return row;
        }

        //if not falling off maze to right
        public int moveEast(int row, int column){
            if (column < m.getGrid()[row].length-1)
                //if tile to right is not a wall (1 value in array)  
            { if(m.getGrid()[row][column+1] != 1)
              {
                p.move(1, 0);
              } else
                {
                    System.out.println("You've hit a wall.");
                }
            } else
              {
                System.out.println("You've hit a wall.");
              }
            return column;
        }

        //if not falling off maze to left
        public int moveWest(int row, int column){
            if (column > 0)
                //if tile to left is not a wall (1 value in array)  
            { if(m.getGrid()[row][column-1] != 1)
              {
                p.move(-1, 0);
              } else
                {
                    System.out.println("You've hit a wall.");
                }
            } else
              {
                System.out.println("You've hit a wall.");
              }
            return column;
        }

        public void keyPressed(String temp){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int row = 0, column = 0;

            while ((row != m.getGrid().length-1) || 
                    (column != m.getGrid()[0].length-1))
            {   
                temp = scan.nextLine();
                if(temp.equals("n"))
                    row = moveNorth(row, column);
                if(temp.equals("e"))
                    column = moveEast(row, column);
                if(temp.equals("s"))
                    row = moveSouth(row, column);
                if(temp.equals("w"))
                    column = moveWest(row, column);
                else
                    //TO DO: implement into GUI text field
                    System.out.println("Invalid Direction"); 
            }
        }
        /*
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source == 
        }
        */
//}
}
package Project;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextPanel extends JPanel {

    //private Dungeon d;

    private JLabel directionLabel; //shows instructions for movement
    private JLabel resultLabel; //shows user input after direction is entered
    private JTextField direction; //allows direction to be entered

    //private JLabel healthLabel, potionsLabel;


    public JTextField getDirection(){
        return direction;
    }

    public TextPanel()
    {
      directionLabel = new JLabel 
            ("Enter n for north, e for east, s for south, and w for west.");
      resultLabel = new JLabel ("---");

      //healthLabel = new JLabel ("Health Points: ");
      //potionsLabel = new JLabel ("Potions Remaining: ");

      direction = new JTextField (5);
      direction.addActionListener (new TempListener());
      add (directionLabel);
      add (direction);
      add (resultLabel);
      //add (healthLabel);
      //add (potionsLabel);

    }


//stores user input for direction
private class TempListener implements ActionListener {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
      {
         String directionGiven;
         directionGiven = direction.getText();

         resultLabel.setText ("You moved: " + directionGiven);

        //d.keyPressed(directionGiven);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: When you implement your gui, is there a reason you still want to make the user type the direction into a text field?  You could simply listen to key events and react any time they press n,s,e,w or any of the arrow keys without actually typing it into the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a reference of `Dungeon` to `TextPanel`

```
public class TextPanel extends JPanel {

    private Dungeon d;
    //...    
    public TextPanel(Dungeon d)
    {
        this.d = d;
```

This way, you can call the methods of `Dungeon` when you need to.  Personally, I prefer to use an `interface` as it limits exactly what `TextPanel` can do, but for simplicity, this will work.

You'll need to restructure your `MazeDriver`'s constructor slightly as well...

```
public class MazeDriver 
{
    public MazeDriver(){  
        Dungeon dungeon = new Dungeon();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Maze Game");
        frame.add(dungeon);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TextPanel panel = new TextPanel(dungeon);
        panel.setBackground (Color.white);
        panel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (800, 400));    

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();              
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to pass references in the constructor to the objects which needed to be invoked. For Example:

```
//stores user input for direction
private class TempListener implements ActionListener {

  private MazeDriver driver;
  public TempListner(MazeDriver driver) {
      this.driver = driver;

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
  {
     String directionGiven;
     directionGiven = direction.getText();

     resultLabel.setText ("You moved: " + directionGiven);

    driver.keyPressed(directionGiven);
  }
}
```

As a general solution, I would make separate classes for the logic (sometimes called business logic) and the user interface. This separated responsibility will make the code easier to understand and maintain.